# Flask GraphQL import fails

Tags: python, graphql, graphql-python

I have the package versions

```
...
Flask               2.0.2
Flask-GraphQL       2.0.0
Flask-Script        2.0.6
...
graphene            3.0
graphql-core        3.1.6
graphql-relay       3.1.0
graphql-server-core 1.1.1
...
```

and when I `import flask_graphql` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Web/Sites/proj/_foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flask_graphql
  File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/proj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_graphql/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .blueprint import GraphQL
  File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/proj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_graphql/blueprint.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .graphqlview import GraphQLView
  File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/proj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_graphql/graphqlview.py", line 7, in <module>
    from graphql_server import (HttpQueryError, default_format_error,
  File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/proj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphql_server/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from graphql import get_default_backend
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_default_backend' from 'graphql' (/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/proj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphql/__init__.py)
```

How do I avoid this error. Are there different versions or version ranges I should be requiring?

Comment: try upgrading Flask-GraphQL vesrion to 2.0.1

Comment: @ZalakBhalani 2.0.0 is what I get with `pip install Flask-GraphQL`. In fact updating to the latest is what triggered this.

Comment: @ZalakBhalani I can get 2.0.1 manually with `pip install Flask-GraphQL==2.0.1` but then I get `graphql-relay 3.1.0 requires graphql-core>=3.1 ...` and `graphene 3.0 requires graphql-core~=3.1.2 ... which is incompatible.`

Comment: @ZalakBhalani Ah I see, `flask-graphql>=2.0.1` in my `requirements.txt` is the way to do it. Then `pip install -U -r requirements.txt` will install the needed versions of `graphql-core`. When was the error above introduced?

Comment: @orome hi, are you solve this problem?

Comment: I got the same problem.

Comment: The error can be reproduced by cloning and running the official graphql example https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/tree/master/examples/flask_sqlalchemy as explained in the repo

Answer (score 0):

An option: Downgrade.

Cost: Losing new features.

How: Pin these packages to these versions:

```
flask-graphql==2.0.1
graphene==2.1.9
graphene-sqlalchemy==2.3.0
```

---

See GitHub issue: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/issues/380

---

Note: If you're trying to get [the Flask example](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/tree/master/examples/flask_sqlalchemy) to work, replace the *entire* contents of `graphene-sqlalchemy/examples/flask_sqlalchemy/requirements.txt` with the above text.

You can test that the Flask example works with this query:

```
{
  allEmployees {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```